# Python sys._getframe

Tags: python

/mypath/test.py

```
import sys

def test():
    frame = sys._getframe(0)
    f = frame.f_code.co_filename
    print('f:', f)
    print('co_filename1:', frame.f_code.co_filename)
    while frame.f_code.co_filename == f:
        frame = frame.f_back
    print('co_filename2:', frame.f_code.co_filename)

test()
```

run it and get:

```
f: /mypath/test.py
co_filename1: /mypath/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mypath/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    test()
  File "/mypath/test.py", line 9, in test
    while frame.f_code.co_filename == f:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'f_code'
```

Why frame.f_code get a NoneType Error in while loop but can print as usual?Thanks~

Comment: Coding error. If *all* stack frames are in the current file (e.g. if you run the file directly), the loop falls off the top of the frame stack. At this point, `frame == None`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you run `frame = frame.f_back` you go back to the previous code frame. When you are on the topmost frame, however, `f_back` attribute contains None (as in "there is no previous frame") - so you should just break off the while loop at that point. Just add an extra  condition to that, for example:

```
while frame and frame.f_code.co_filename == f:
        frame = frame.f_back
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
while frame and frame.f_code.co_filename == f:
    if frame.f_back is None:
        break
    else:
        frame = frame.f_back
```

Comment: This is no better than the accepted answer, actually is longer (and the changes are redundant).